# How can I write a registry key from VS post build event?

Tags: visual-studio, post-build-event, build-events

One of the projects I work on need to read a registry key in order to determine some value. Usually the value will be written during installation.

Because I want to run the project locally as well (without installation) I want to write that value after the build has finished.

Is there a simple way I can do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Searching the web I've found this cool tool that comes with windows called [REG.EXE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg)

Using it from within VS is simple - **REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\\ /v NUnitDir /t REG_SZ /d  /f**

Answer (score 2):

You can create a small program that creates your registry key and call that program in the post build event.

**Edit**
If you can extract your registry settings to a file, you can add this to you post build event:
`regedit /s $(ProjectDir)test.reg`

/s makes it silent.

Comment: I know but I rather use a built in windows utility